# On updation of data set of recycler view list ,it's scroll jumps back to the top (duplicate)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used recycler view to show data in the list.

In my application, I am running one service after each 10 sec time interval to update data in the list.
Now the problem is when I get the data from the service each time list scrolls jumps back to the top position.

I don't know what's wrong with the code.

I have gone through following links but nothing worked out.

[Recyclerview Position changing to first position when I Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776696/recyclerview-position-changing-to-first-position-when-i-update)

[Refresh recyclerView adapter with new items on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417951/refresh-recyclerview-adapter-with-new-items-on-top)

[notifyDataSetChanged() makes the list refresh and scroll jumps back to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695594/notifydatasetchanged-makes-the-list-refresh-and-scroll-jumps-back-to-the-top)

[Android ListView - scrolls back to top on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877848/android-listview-scrolls-back-to-top-on-update)

below is the code to initialize recycler view.

```
    mTableOrderAdapter = new 
    TableOrderAdapter(MainActivity.this,tableOrderModelArrayList);
    rvTableOrders.setHasFixedSize(true);

    rvTableOrders.setLayoutManager(new 
    GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1));
    rvTableOrders.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    rvTableOrders.setAdapter(mTableOrderAdapter);
```

when I am getting data from service I just add it into the list and call following method.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mTableOrderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();    
                }
            });
```

Please help me to get rid of this.
Sorry for the English.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just use SwipeRefreshLayout which was solved my issue.

Visit https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface